# jquery show / hide accordion - close open item if open

Tags: jquery, accordion

Ok so that might be a confusing title, essentially I have made a FAQ show/hide function, which will close any open items, and then open the item you just clicked on. However, I need it to close the item you have open, if you click on it's title again (if that makes sense?)

```
<div class="faq">
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-1">question 1</a></h3>
  <div id="item-1" class="items">
    answer 1
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-2">question 2</a></h3>
  <div id="item-2" class="items">
    answer 2
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-3">question 3</a></h3>
  <div id="item-3" class="items">
    answer 3
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-4">question 4</a></h3>
  <div id="item-4" class="items">
    answer 4
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.faq h3 a:not(.open)').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('open');
        var faq = $.attr(this,'href').substr(1);
        $('.faq .items').slideUp('fast');
        $('.faq #'+faq).slideDown('fast',function(){
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('[id="'+faq+'"]').offset().top-60},750);
        });
    });
    $('.faq h3 a.open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.faq .items').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
</script>
```

So if I clicked on question 3, it opens, and if I click on it again, it closes. But if I click on question 2, it closes question 3 and opens question 2.

I tried adding an open class, but it's ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach, when manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

```
$('.faq h3').on('click', 'a:not(.open)', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('open');
    var faq = $.attr(this,'href').substr(1);
    $('.faq .items').slideUp('fast');
    $('.faq #'+faq).slideDown('fast',function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('[id="'+faq+'"]').offset().top-60},750);
    });
});
$('.faq h3').on('click', 'a.open', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.faq .items').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

---

However you can simplify you code as

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.faq h3 a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItem = $(this).parent().next('.items');
    $('.faq .items').not(nextItem).slideUp('fast');
    nextItem.slideDown('fast', function() {
      if (nextItem.is(':visible')) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: nextItem.offset().top - 60
        }, 750);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.items {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-1">question 1</a></h3>
  <div id="item-1" class="items">
    answer 1
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-2">question 2</a></h3>
  <div id="item-2" class="items">
    answer 2
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-3">question 3</a></h3>
  <div id="item-3" class="items">
    answer 3
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h3><a href="#item-4">question 4</a></h3>
  <div id="item-4" class="items">
    answer 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LeanneSeawright, I have also provide an alternate solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this code might be helpful :

JQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item h3').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.items').slideToggle();
    })
});
```

HMTL markup :

```
    <div class="faq">
        <hr />
        <div class="item">
            <h3><a href="#item-1">question 1</a></h3>
            <div id="item-1" class="items">
                answer 1
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h3><a href="#item-2">question 2</a></h3>
            <div id="item-2" class="items">
                answer 2
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h3><a href="#item-3">question 3</a></h3>
            <div id="item-3" class="items">
                answer 3
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h3><a href="#item-4">question 4</a></h3>
            <div id="item-4" class="items">
                answer 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```